# Ubuntu keeps asking me for an authentication code when I download anything

Tags: downloads

Im currently trying to download Dropbox, but it's asking for a "Password" that was not given to me as the download shouldn't require an authentication code, i've been running into this problem alot but I absolutely need Dropbox working by tomorrow. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Fill in your user password. Its your Ubuntu password, not Dropbox. After finish installation you will be prompt to enter Dropbox username and password.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Are you an Administrator? (You can check this searching "User Accounts" in the dash menu.

If you are an administrator, you should check your password, if you forgot it, you should read [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/), but instead of pressing the "ESC" key, press "Shift", as this guide is a little old, but it still works (at least in Ubuntu 11.10).

If you are not an Administrator, you should ask your's to help you, as a normal user cannot install Software.

Good Luck!